# 2 Buttons with sound on click

Tags: android, button, audio, click

Here is the code from main activity

I use Android Studio:

import...

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
public MediaPlayer mp;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Button lol2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.lol2);
    lol2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.lol2);
            mp.start();
        }
    });
    final Button app2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.app2);
    app2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),R.raw.app2);
            mp.start();
        }
   });
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

Button in .XML

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Test"
    android:id="@+id/lol2"
```

Both buttons play the sounds... But when I click too often I get an error and it does not work anymore... why?

### Edit:

When i click 10 times on a button it works... but if i click more and more on the button(s) they do not play the sound anymore. :-(

The App works after many clicks on the buttons but there is no sound anymore.

"mp.isPlaying();" if false then... ? i do not understand this.

Comment: What error you are getting? Please post your error also. Without error no one is going to understand your problem.

Comment: I think you have to check for mediaplayer is playing or not to again play another song on click of second button. check that `mp.isPlaying(); // returns true or false`. If it returns true then stop already created instance and then again play it

Answer (score 0):

try creating two MediaPlayer variables